# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection after migrating to weblogic 12c

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic12c

We have migrated war file from weblogic 11g to 12c.After migration when hibernate createQuery is running below exception is coming.We are using hibernate 3.6.10

ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' - >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> transactionorg.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction@28e357b3
[2020-02-12 23:00:49,426] [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' - >>>>>>>>>>>. transaction exception >>>>>>>>>>>>> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
[2020-02-12 23:00:49,428] [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' - status query:::::select c.status,c.id.subscrType from Test c where c.id.mob=:mobilenumber
[2020-02-12 23:00:49,428] [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' - This is inside query checking >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >>>2112: org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction

Comment: Can you show code of how you are opening a session? Creating a transaction?

Comment: Session session1 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
      trx = session1.getTransaction();
      System.out.println("trx >>" + trx);
      trx.begin();
      String query = "select c.status,c.id.subscrType from Test c where c.id.subNo=:msisdn";
      logger.debug("status query:::::" + query);
      obj = session1.createQuery(query).setString("msisdn", mobile).list();
      session1.flush();

Comment: To my understanding, I believe you need to do session1.beginTransaction().    According to documentation:  Begin a unit of work and return the associated Transaction object. If a new underlying transaction is required, begin the transaction. Otherwise continue the new work in the context of the existing underlying transaction.

So it only starts a new transaction (if none exists)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854746/hibernate-active-transaction